# How to only run a command in .bash_profile if its not already running?

Tags: bash, osx, socat, bash-profile

**Goal:**
Run `socat` only once.
I'm trying to expose `docker` web services via TCP.  On macOS/linux these services are bound to a unix socket.  The following command accomplishes the task:

```
socat -d TCP-LISTEN:2376,range=127.0.0.1/32,reuseaddr,fork UNIX:/var/run/docker.sock
```

So I don't have to remember to type this all the time, I'd like it to start when the computer starts.  I don't know how to accomplish that particular goal, but I have done a little bit of work with `.bash_profile`.  So I'll settle for running `socat` whenever a `terminal` runs.  However, since `.bash_profile` runs for every `terminal` instance, I'd like a mechanism that only runs the command if it's not already running.  But I don't know how to check, from `.bash_profile` if something is already running.  Can you help?

Comment: @NasirRiley: probably because I'm not familiar with those.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that command to start at boot then you can just use a `cronjob`.

As root:

```
crontab -e
```

Next, enter the following just like you would in a text editor:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/socat -d TCP-LISTEN:2376,range=127.0.0.1/32,reuseaddr,fork UNIX:/var/run/docker.sock
```

That tells `crontab` to run your command when the system boots. Make sure that there is a new line following the command by pressing `ENTER` after it. Enter `:wq!` just like you would in `vim` to save it.

Reboot your system and then `grep` for the command to make sure that it's running.

```
ps aux | grep socat
```